# scatterplot using multiple colors for single point

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Looking to use two separate colors for points in a scatter plot. This works, however, the second points still contain the first color and are only outlined by the second color. See example below.

[image]

code used to generate this problem:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_swiss_roll
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

swiss_roll, _ = make_swiss_roll(n_samples=100, noise=0.05, random_state=None)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#plot swiss roll
for xs, ys, zs in swiss_roll:
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, color='b')

gs = np.random.uniform(-15 , 15, (100, 3))

for xs, ys, zs in gs:
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, color='r')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

I am plotting in separate loops because there is code in between to generate gs.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. You're leaving people guessing as to what `gs` is, as well as what your imports are. I'm presuming `make_swiss_roll` isn't in the standard library.

Comment: Sorry, that may have come across a bit harsh. Haven't had the morning coffee yet. I personally like to be able to copy/paste a block of code when playing with problems like this, and it really helps not having to figure out where to get my imports, and what data I need to provide.

Comment: no need to apologize, I'm the one who is asking for help :D

Comment: So running the exact code posted, I'm not getting any issues - both datasets are coloured in their respective red and blue. I'm running Python 3 in a Jupyter Notebook if that helps.

Comment: interesting, must only be a problem with python2.7 then. I just tried on python3 and had no issues.

Comment: Looks like it. If you don't have a particular reason to work with 2.7, I'd be going with 3 anyway.